# Python 3 : Unable to convert binary data to text

Tags: python, binary, hex

In one of my project I want to transfer a binary file which is the firmware of a microcontroller : "firmware.bin". It looks like this :

> 007c 0020 4da0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
>   49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
>   49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 018a 0000 49a0 0000 bd82 0000 058a 0000
>   098a 0000 7182 0000 118a 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
>   49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
>   49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000  ...

The content is printed on an URL which I call to retrieve the data. On the URL it is converted to text and looks like this :

> �|�
>   M���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I������I����������    ���q������I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���I���

...

When I read it back, I get the following :

> 007c 0020 4def bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000
>   49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd
>   0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef
>   bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 01ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000
>   efbf bdef bfbd 0000 05ef bfbd 0000 09ef bfbd 0000 71ef bfbd 0000 11ef
>   bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd 0000 49ef bfbd

which is different from what I had in the first place.

This is the code :

```
# download the data
r = requests.get(URL);

# save it to bin file
data = r.text.encode('utf-8')
f.write(bytes(data))
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

I found a solution. I was using *echo file_get_contents($file)* to print my binary file in my PHP program. Seems like it cuts some characters like 0x00... So now I am using : *echo bin2hex(file_get_contents($file))*, retrieve the full data in a string in my Python program and dump it to the file with *f.write(bytes.fromhex(data))*

Comment: you can try this: `data. decode('ascii')`

Comment: Show the code used to download the data. You definitely do not encode binary data, but to encode you must have decoded the data already, and that is incorrect as well.

Comment: I updated the source code. I am using Python 3

Comment: The URL doesn't seem to be properly escaped.  There is a very specific set of characters supported in a URL so it should not have these � characters.

Comment: The URL says that the text is encoding using UTF-8.